# Flutter - Overlay card widget on a container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, overlay, flutter-widget

In flutter, is it possible to place a part of a card on another container? In CSS, we would set margin-top to a negative value or use translate property. In flutter as we cannot set negative values to margin-top, is there an alternative to that?

[image]

Comment: For your question "is it possible?", of course yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using stack widget.. but was not able to overlay only part of a widget on another one..

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, you can acheive it with a `Stack` widget. You can stack a card over the background and provide a top or bottom padding.

A simple example would look like:

```
class StackDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        // The containers in the background
        new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .35,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        ),
        // The card widget with top padding, 
        // incase if you wanted bottom padding to work, 
        // set the `alignment` of container to Alignment.bottomCenter
        new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .58,
              right: 20.0,
              left: 20.0),
          child: new Container(
            height: 200.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 4.0,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the above code would look something like:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Instead of hardcoding `Positioned` or `Container`, you should use `Align`.

**Code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container(color: Colors.indigo)),
            Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.white)),
          ],
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
          child: Container(
            width: size.width * 0.9,
            height: size.height * 0.4,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 12,
              child: Center(child: Text('CARD', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer.  You mean the others are not responsive where as this one is right?  I'm coming from HTML, CSS, Bootstrap so I really dislike hard coding anything for layout unless that is the only option.

Comment: By the way, nesting stacks is okay right? Say I want a little half circle sticking out the top of the card for my user avatar like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343527/flutter-a-card-with-a-circleavatar-which-stick-out

Comment: @mLstudent33 Yes, nesting like that in Flutter isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is running example with overlay:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
     double _width = 0.0;
     double _height = 0.0;

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          // The containers in the background and scrollable
         getScrollableBody(),

         // This container will work as Overlay
         getOverlayWidget()
        ],
      ),
   );
 }

 Widget getOverlayWidget() {
   return new Container(
     alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
     child: new Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: _width,
      color: Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.4),
     ),
   );
 }
 Widget getScrollableBody() {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
         height: _height * .65,
         color: Colors.yellow,
       ),
       new Container(
         height: _height * .65,
         color: Colors.brown,
       ),
       new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
        height: _height * .65,
        color: Colors.orange,
       ),
     ],
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Here is Result of code: 
[Scrollable Body under customised Bottom Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3WKW.png)