# Flutter: A Card with a CircleAvatar, which stick out

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a card with a `CircleAvatar`, which stick out (you can see the details in this picture):

[image: Card]

I don't know, how it could work :/ I tried something with a `Stack` and the Positioned Widget, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think @Rémi Rousselet way is better but here is another way to do it using `FractionalTranslation` so you can play more with the position of the `CircleAvatar`

```
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      child: Container(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
            FractionalTranslation(
              translation: Offset(0.0, -0.4),
              child: Align(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25.0,
                  child: Text("A"),
                ),
                alignment: FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> test :

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      CustomCard(),
      CustomCard(),
      CustomCard(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`Stack` indeed is the solution.

[image]

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 100.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Foo",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                ),
                Text("bar")
              ],
            ),
          )),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: .0,
      left: .0,
      right: .0,
      child: Center(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30.0,
          child: Text("D"),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: how do I get the blue circle D sticking out the top though?

Comment: That is so weird how the image here does not look like it is sticking out but when I used it, it is.  Thanks for a huge tip!

Comment: But...when I resize the CircleAvatar, it is now only sticking out the top a little bit.  I tried using negative numbers for top but it does help.

Comment: This worked, Align can go into negatives beyond -1.0: ```Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, -1.2),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30.0,
                    child: Center(
                      //alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                      child: Text("Room 33"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),`

Answer (score 4):

I also needed a card with circular image at the top. Got an idea from @Rémi Rousselet 's answer. Thought it might benefit you too.

Result of the code.

[image]

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Card(
          color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 0, left: 10, right: 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Dr. Maseed", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Text("Dr. Maseed is a radiation oncologist in Indianapolis, Indiana and is affiliated with multiple hospitals in the area. He has been in practice for more than 20 years.", style: TextStyle()),
                    ButtonBar(children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(child: Text("APPOINTMENT", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),), onPressed: (){},)
                    ],)
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    ),
    Utils.circularImageWithBorder(
        "assets/images/maseed.png", 30, 2, Colors.black),
  ],
),
```

A static method to return a circular avatar.

```
static Widget circularImageWithBorder(String imgPath, double rad, double borderWidth, Color borderColor) {
  return CircleAvatar(
      radius: rad + borderWidth,
      backgroundColor: borderColor,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: AssetImage(imgPath),
        radius: rad,
      ));
}
```