# Overlay card widget over NestedScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter

In my screen I am already using `NestedScrollView()` along with `headerSliverBuilder` and `SliverAppBar()`. I tried to add a Stack widget to the body of headerSliverBuilder but it never came in between the blue and white part as expected (expected result in the screenshot). It stays on the white portion only. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49404698/1010370) answer but failed as mentioned above. Here is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post you code? It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

call the `Stack` from your `Scaffold` body instead, not the `headerSliverBuilder`