# How to overlay Widget over background widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to overlay a **add to cart** button on background restaurants list, [Overlay card widget on container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402837/flutter-overlay-card-widget-on-a-container) explains it can be done by **Stack** but I tried and still not getting how to do it. Kindly help me to know how can I do it?

Expected Design

[image]

Result Image

[image]

detailpage.dart

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Wrap(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(...),
          Container(...),
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 88,
                    height: 30,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff00D99E),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 8,
                              offset: Offset(0, 15),
                              color: Color(0xff00D99E).withOpacity(.6),
                              spreadRadius: -9)
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset('assets/icon-chat-notification.png'),
                        SizedBox(width: 6),
                        Text("CART",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              letterSpacing: 1,
                            ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `Stack` only composes the Button itself instead of the entire view, you use it to put the Text and the Icon on top of the `MaterialButton`. Side note: that's actually not necessary, you can just put the text and the icon directly into the `MaterialButton` and get rid of the Stack.

To solve your problem you have to put your button and your List onto the same `Stack` (your button can still stay a `Stack` itself but I don't encourage you to do that).

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(...),
          // Use Positioned around your List to expand it in all dimensions
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(...), // This is your container with the list
          )
          // Position the button at the bottom
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Stack(...), // This is your button
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }
```